# "needless to say" - How to use it in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

> I don't need to say that if there is no more rain, then only we will go out for a dinner.

How do I use "needless to say" in such a sentences?

> Needless to say, if there is no more rain, then only we will go out for a dinner.

Comment: It's better to avoid use of self-contradictory phrases like “needless to say” and “I don't need to say”.  If you don't need to say something, then don't say it.  If you *do* need to say something, then don't call it *needless*.

Comment: Side note: "then only we will go out for a dinner" is awkward. The more natural phrasing would be, "We will only go out for dinner if there is no more rain". If you want to put the part about rain first for emphasis, you could say, "Only if there is no more rain will we go out for dinner." That is, a limiting word or phrase such as "only" is normally placed before the condition that it applies to, in this case "if there is no more rain", not to the action that depends on that condition.

Comment: Also, we normally say "go out to dinner", not "go out to a dinner". "A dinner" -- with the article -- refers to a formal event. Like, "We held a dinner to raise funds for charity". On ordinary meal is simply "dinner" with no article.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Needless to say" means the same as *obviously* when placed at the beginning of a satement.

It is either used as [hedging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_%28linguistics%29), i.e. the speaker makes the statement but points out that they think it's obvious just in case the statement really is obvious, or it is used to boost the speaker's ego, i.e. the statement might not be obvious but they make it seem like it is to make the listener think that the speaker is clever.

For example:

> The height a body of water is affected by gravity, so the more mass land has the more an ocean is pulled towards it. **Needless to say**, because of this, the melt water from the Greenland icesheets will cause higher water levels in the southern hemisphere, while lowering the water levels in the nothern hemisphere.

As you can see "needless to say" is normally put before, or within, some concluding statement.

You could also use it parenthetically:

> It is, needless to say, very cold in November.

Comment: I would then suggest `We will obviously only go out for dinner if the rain stops`